# CSS Layers Z-Index IE8 Compatability Mode - Drop Down Menu

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, layer

I'm fairly incompetent at this but after months of playing, exploring and reading I've finally got my company website to a presentable state.  Only one minor issue before I release it.  And I realise this has been asked and answered a million times but for the life of me I can't figure out how to fix it on my particular page.

All works wonderfully in Chrome, Firefox and IE 9 & 10 (as appears often the case).  In IE8, when in compatability mode, the hover over sub-menu is sitting behind a sliding banner.  I presume this would be the same in IE7 if I'd bothered to test it.

http://www.globalsafetytandc.com/index.html

I've been trying to fix this all day.  My CSS now has z-index values everywhere and still to no avail.  I seek your learned opinion.  Be gentle with me.  I have no real experience of this development lark - just an inquisitive mind that has got me this far.

Thanks,
Simon

Comment: Read this and the FAQ: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Answer (score 0):

For IE8 compatibility add this line in the head of the html file:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=100" />
```